# Cannot get keyboard key from variable

Tags: python, keyboard, tkinter-entry, pyautogui, pynput

So I'm trying to make a program that can hold/autoclick keyboard keys.
The problem is, the program doesn't understand the key to press from the variable (obtained from Tkinter Entry) I give it.

When I use pynput to press the key, it says that I haven't given it a value:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

When I use pyautogui to press the key, it doesn't do anything, it doesn't even return an error.

Part of the code not working:

```
        #Autoclicking keyboard key (using pynput) (not working)
        #hold = whether to autoclick or hold key
        #clkdel = delay between keyboard presses
        #keyprsd = key to be pressed (tk.StringVar)
        #lf7 = listener for when to start/stop
        if int(hold.get()) == 1:
            print('Starting keyboard pressing...')
            while self.run == True:
                print('Pressed')
                master.after(clkdel, keyct.press(keyprsd.get()))
            lf7.stop()
```

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput import keyboard
import pyautogui

class GUI:
   def __init__(self, master):
       #Defining variables
       hold = tk.IntVar()
       keyprsd = tk.StringVar()
       self.run = False
       msbt = tk.IntVar()
       mousect = Controller()
       keyct = Controller()
       #Creating main window
       master = master
       master.title('Key Clicker')
       master.geometry('250x250')
       master.resizable(False, False)
       #Creating radio buttons:
       #Autoclick button
       self.autoclick = tk.Radiobutton(master, text='Autoclick', variable=hold, value=1)
       self.autoclick.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='en', padx=30, pady=5)
       #Hold button
       self.holdbt = tk.Radiobutton(master, text='Hold', variable=hold, value=2)
       self.holdbt.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='wn', padx=0, pady=5)
       #Creating keyboard button label
       self.kbtlabel = tk.Label(master, textvariable=keyprsd, width=10, bg='Light Blue')
       self.kbtlabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='wens')
       #Creating keyboard button detection:
       #Functions to detect key to be pressed
       def lforsetkey():
           lst = Listener(on_press=ksetcall)
           lst.start()
       def ksetcall(key):
           print('{} was pressed'.format(key))
           keyprsd.set(key)
           return False
       #Functions to detect when to start and stop autoclicking/holding
       def f7press(key):
           print('{} was pressed'.format(key))
           if key == keyboard.Key.f7:
               self.run = False
           if key == keyboard.Key.f6:
               self.run = True
               stmouse()
           if key == keyboard.Key.f8:
               self.run = True
               stkey()
       def lforf7():
           global lf7
           lf7 = Listener(on_press=f7press)
           lf7.start()
       lforf7()
       #Creating key selection button
       self.kbtsel = tk.Button(master, text='Click and press a key', command=lforsetkey)
       self.kbtsel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='wen', padx=0)
       #Creating list for mouse buttons
       self.mslft = tk.Radiobutton(master, text='Left Click', variable=msbt, value=1)
       self.mslft.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='en', padx=10)
       self.msrft = tk.Radiobutton(master, text='Right Click', variable=msbt, value=2)
       self.msrft.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='en', padx=10)
       #Creating autoclick frequency label
       self.clklb = tk.Label(master, text='Autoclick frequency (ms)')
       self.clklb.grid(row=3, column=0)
       #Creating autoclick frequency entry
       self.clkent = tk.Entry(master)
       self.clkent.grid(row=3, column=1)
       #Creating mouse autoclick button
       def stmouse():
           self.run = True
           lforf7()
           try:
               clkdel = int(self.clkent.get())
           except ValueError:
               print('Value Error')
           #Autoclicking left button
           if int(msbt.get()) == 1 and int(hold.get()) == 1:
               print('Starting mouse autoclick...')
               while self.run == True:
                   print('Clicked')
                   master.after(clkdel, mousect.click(Button.left))
               lf7.stop()
           #Autoclicking right button
           elif int(msbt.get()) == 2 and int(hold.get()) == 1:
               print('Starting mouse autoclick...')
               while self.run == True:
                   print('Clicked')
                   master.after(clkdel, mousect.click(Button.right))
               lf7.stop()
           #Holding left button
           elif int(msbt.get()) == 1 and int(hold.get()) == 2:
               print('Starting mouse holding...')
               while self.run == True:
                   pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
               lf7.stop()
               pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
           #Holding right button
           elif int(msbt.get()) == 2 and int(hold.get()) == 2:
               print('Starting mouse holding...')
               while self.run == True:
                   pyautogui.mouseDown(button='right')
               lf7.stop()
               pyautogui.mouseUp(button='right')
           else:
               print('Error')
       self.msbt = tk.Button(master, text='Click to start holding/autoclicking mouse', command=stmouse)
       self.msbt.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='swe', pady=5)
       #Creating keyboard button
       def stkey():
           #Setting up variables and starting listener
           self.run = True
           lforf7()
           try:
               clkdel = int(self.clkent.get())
           except ValueError:
               print('Value Error')
           #Autoclicking keyboard key (using pynput) (not working)
           #hold = whether to autoclick or hold key
           #clkdel = delay between keyboard presses
           #keyprsd = key to be pressed (tk.StringVar)
           #lf7 = listener for when to start/stop
           if int(hold.get()) == 1:
               print('Starting keyboard pressing...')
               while self.run == True:
                   print('Pressed')
                   master.after(clkdel, keyct.press(keyprsd.get()))
               lf7.stop()
           #Holding keyboard key (also not working)
           elif int(hold.get()) == 2:
               print('Holding keyboard...')
               while self.run == True:
                   pyautogui.keyDown(keyprsd.get())
               lf7.stop()
               print('Stopping')
               pyautogui.keyUp(keyprsd.get())
           else:
               print('Error')
       self.kbt = tk.Button(master, text='Click to start holding/autoclicking keyboard', command=stkey)
       self.kbt.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='swe', pady=5)
root = tk.Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: error shows that you have string  and you shouldn't use `.value`

Comment: BTW: instead `int(hold.get()) == 1` you can compare strings `hold.get() == "1"`

Comment: BTW: very big mistake - `after()` (similar to `command=` and `bind()`) needs function's name without `()` - if you need function with arguments then use `after(..., function, arg1, arg2, ...)`. At this moment it executes this function at start and it uses result from function in `after()`

Comment: your code is unreadable - you should move nested function outside class or create class methods instead of nested function

Comment: your problem can be that you assign the same mouse controllor to `mousect = Controller()`  and  `keyct = Controller()` but you should use different controllers - `pynput.keyboard.Controller` and `pynput.mouse.Controller`. These controllers are different and they may expect different values. Keyboard controller may expect string but mouse controllre may expect object with `.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main problem is that you import only mouse controller

```
   from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
```

and you use it for mouse and keyboard

```
   mousect = Controller()
   keyct = Controller()
```

but they have different controllers which work in different way.

Keyboard controller can get string but mouse controller expects object with `.value`

You should use differenet controlers

```
   from pynput import mouse
   from pynput import keyboard

   mousect = mouse.Controller()
   keyct = keyboard.Controller()
```

and this resolves main problem.

---

But there is other problem - `after()` (similar to `command=` and `bind()`) expects function name without arguments and you could use `lambda` (like in `command=` or `bind()`) or you have to use arguments after function name

```
   master.after(clkdel, keyct.press, keyprsd.get())

   master.after(clkdel, mousect.click, Button.left)

   master.after(clkdel, mousect.click, Button.right)
```

---

**BTW:** other problem is that your code is unreadable. You should move nested function outside class or create class method and then you will no need `global` but `self.`. You could use also more readable names - ie. `key_controller` is more readable then `keyct`.

See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

`Listener` gives special object with information about key and you put it in `StringVar` as string and later you get it from `StringVar` as string and use this string in `press()` - and it can works for normal keys but not for sprecial keys.

You have to keep original object and use this object in `press()` for all keys (normal and special). ie.

```
   def ksetcall(key):

       self.key = key   # keep original object 

       print('{} was pressed'.format(key))
       keyprsd.set(key)
       return False
```

and later

```
 keyct.press(self.key)
```

instead of `keyct.press(keyprsd.get())`

Comment: So, I've applied all your improvements and it works!
Although I still have another problem: I can't autoclick/hold keys like ctrl, shift, etc...
Pynput throws out a Value error, pyautogui doesn't do anything. Full code here:
https://pastebin.com/LK4X2HGA

Comment: what error? You could remove `try/except` to see full error. Or at least you should use `except ValueError as ex: print(ex)` to see something more.

Comment: I have removed the try/except, but it gives me the same details of the error:
https://pastebin.com/sqZGPciw

Comment: `Listener` gives you special object with information about key and you put it in `Entry` as string and later you get it from `Entry` as string and use this string in `press()` - and it can works for normal keys but not for sprecial keys. You have to keep original object and use this object in `press()` for all keys (normal and special). ie. `def ksetcall(self, key): self.key = key ....` and later `press(self.key)`, `release(self.key)`